# Ruby fast extract from csv

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file with just about 6million lines of data.  Im looking the fastest way to extract rows only with certain info.  One of the Header entries is countries.  Im looking to just extract rows that have country as 'US'

```
require 'fastest-csv'    

line_num = 1
FastestCSV.foreach('geoIPCity.csv') do |csv_obj|

  if csv_obj[2] == 'US'
    us_ips << csv_obj
  end

 puts "read line: #{line_num}"
 line_num += 1
end
```

this way takes roughly 5-10 mins.

is there anything faster ?

Comment: out of curiosity I would try `grep` and compare how much faster it is.

Comment: I was thinking in the same general direction as @akonsu : if the number of records that have "US" are small in comparison to the file's size, how about opening the file as text, scanning each line for "US", and CSV-parsing only the records that contain that? On the other hand, is US is half of the file or more, that will probably make it slower.

Comment: from my last calculation, its about 1,291,791 of the said 6,000,000. I have a similar code in perl that im trying to replicate in ruby. The problem though is speed.

Comment: `puts "read line"` etc. 6,000,000 times takes a lot of time. Better display every 10,000 lines or so.

Comment: Have you considered using the native CSV import ability of a database, import your data, then a quick query to extract and export just what you want? Those tools should be running as compiled C or C++ and will be extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is probably your best bet if you're on a system with it available.  Try this:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /US/' geoIPCity.csv
```

You can do it within Ruby by doing something like:

```
out = `awk -F, '$2 ~ /US/' geoIPCity.csv`
# all the lines of the CSV that matches
```

Could then feed those lines back in your favorite CSV parser if you need to do something w/it.